# How do I dynamically link a local created npm package to another project?

Tags: npm, webstorm, npm-link

I have a project that exports a package to be used by other projects (some infra code).
I've published it in a local repo, and then installed it on my main project.
I need to keep working on that infra project, and to have it updated in the larger project. I have no problem running scripts to do that - but I don't want to increase its package version and to keep publishing it on any change.

I know about `npm link` and I've been trying to use it, but it seems that some caching in WebStorm causes it to not update in the main project. I actually need sometimes to invalidate caches and restart the IDE after changes to the infra package - and that's a large time consumer.

Is there a way to tell WebStom "for this npm package I want you to use this path instead of the actual npm package"? Or to use the "Attach project" feature to do that when both are open?

Edit: After working like that a bit, I've discovered that the need to invalidate cache is related only to TS related changes - meaning when I add classes or change signatures. I can write the correct code and it works - but TS shows errors and no autocomplete until I invalidate the caches. And restarting TS service doesn't help.

Comment: git-submodules is one way to spell out external repo dependencies; it also allows for tracking versions for your main project and external repos independently.

Comment: @KodeCharlie git-submodules actually put the infra package as a physical part of the main project. Now let's say I want to reuse it in another project - I won't be able to edit the infra package easily because it won't be a submodule of that another project.